# Placing a icon to display text onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed an e-commerce site. For user form input box, i want to put a question mark icon as help tool. When user takes mouse on that icon it should display the help text. I am not getting how to do it. Please someone help me in doing this .

Thanks

Comment: try to do it in whatever way you imagine, we will try to help you to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a div that is hidden and show it on mouse hover.. If you are looking for some cool tool tips you can use Qtip..

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('img[title]').qtip({
      content: {
         text: false // Use each elements title attribute
      },
      style: 'cream' // Give it some style
   });
});
```

Comment: But make sure u include the qtip.js file into ur project

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea for you. http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing a [search for JQuery tooltips](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery%20tooltip%20plugin&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1#hl=en&safe=off&qscrl=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20input%20tooltip%20plugin&oq=jquery%20input%20tooltip%20plugin&gs_l=serp.3..33i29l4.21223.22678.0.23434.8.8.0.0.0.5.319.1839.1j0j5j2.8.0.les;..1.0...1c.1.EeMg5JKeSAg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d13db64a30626e57&biw=1366&bih=643) will really help.

I found this: http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

You can just use it like this:

```
$('#my-html-element').poshytip();
```

If you annotate your icon with a class or id, the above call is all you would need.

It also supports form elements like input boxes like this :

```
$('#demo-form-name').poshytip({
    className: 'tip-yellowsimple',
    showOn: 'focus',
    alignTo: 'target',
    alignX: 'right',
    alignY: 'center',
    offsetX: 5
});
```